# create multiple collapse when i use for loop in Django template

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

How to create multiple collapse when i use for loop in Django template

I have created a django template which show lists of lessons and i want to create collapse for each lesson such that on click of it , it shows the video from my url . how i can do this

html code :

```
    <div id="accordion">
  {% for lesson in course_posts.lesson_set.all %}
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
    <h5 class="mb-0 text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
         {{lesson.name}}
      </button>
    </h5>
  </div>

  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
    <div class="card-body">

      <iframe width="100%" height="400px" src="{{lesson.youtube_url}}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to collapse to work properly each collapsible item should have unique `id`. In your code id will be same. Hence it won't work. Moreover `id` should be unique value.

```
 <div id="accordion">
  {% for lesson in course_posts.lesson_set.all %}
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading{{lesson.id}}">
        <h5 class="mb-0 text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{lesson.id}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{lesson.id}}">
         {{lesson.name}}
           </button>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div id="collapse{{lesson.id}}" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading{{lesson.id}}" data-parent="#accordion">
         <div class="card-body">
             <iframe width="100%" height="400px" src="{{lesson.youtube_url}}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
             </iframe>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```